# Please help me with this Arithmetic problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A man arranges to pay off a debt of $3600 by 40 annual instalments which form an arithmetic series. When 30 of the instalments are paid, he dies leaving a third of the debt unpaid : find the value of the first instalment.

Answer (score 0):

Since the man has to pay the debt in 40 installments,

$$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{40} \left( a + \left( n - 1 \right) d \right) = 3600$$

$$\therefore 2a + 39d = 180$$

Also, the last 10 installments is equal to one - third of the total debt.

$$\therefore \sum\limits_{n = 31}^{40} \left( a + \left( n - 1 \right) d \right) = \dfrac{1}{3} \times 3600$$

$$\therefore 10a + 345d = 1200$$

On solving the simultaneous equations obtained above in $a$ and $d$, we get $a = 51 $.

Thus, the first installment should be of $\$ 51$.

Comment: how the other equation is 10a + 345d = 1200?

Comment: The remaining $10$ terms give $10a$ and the sum $30 +31 + 32 + \dots + 39 = 345$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is the first instalment and $r$ the increment of the arithmetic series the sum of the first $n$ terms will be

$$S_n=n{2a+(n-1)r\over 2}$$

We know $S_{30}=2400$ and $S_{40}=3600$ and this translates into the system of linear equations

$$\begin{cases}
30a+435r=2400\\
40a+780r=3600
\end{cases}$$

the solution is $a=51$ and $r=2$